# Replacing php links to static links

Tags: php, html

I have script which uses absolute addressing in most areas, now I need to change them to relative addressing. But then the issue I am facing here is that, if for instance I have a website named

```
www.example.com
```

Now I want to change the links in php from

```
<link href="<?php print $theme; ?>style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="<?php print $theme; ?>css/colorpicker.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

to

```
<link href="http://www.example.com/<?php print $theme; ?>style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="http://www.example.com/<?php print $theme; ?>css/colorpicker.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

But I end up getting this result

```
<link href="http://www.example.com/http://www.example.com/themes/in/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="http://www.example.com/http://www.example.com/themes/in/css/colorpicker.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I know something is wrong somewhere, but I still can't get it to work.. Any help with correct formatting will be highly appreciated. Sorry if my title for question is inappropriate.

Comment: Remove `<?php print $theme; ?>` from your link code.

Comment: You should check what is in `$theme` variable and why

Comment: @Chris: please make sure you have not included the base path at "$theme" vairbale?

Comment: it mean `$theme;` containing that link

Comment: Ok i removed     <?php print $theme; ?> from the link code, and added /themes/in/styles.css. This worked... Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their would be two possible solutions, either you remove the

```
http://www.example.com/
```

from starting of `<?php print $theme; ?>` OR only include 
    theme name rather than with base bath.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the url setup:

```php
<?php
$path  = explode('/', $theme);
$theme = end($path);
?>
<link href="http://www.example.com/themes/<?= $theme ?>/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This will split the url in pieces and picks the last item which is I think is the theme name you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$theme` contains this url 'http://www.example.com/themes/in/'. So if you just want the url to be like this

`http://www.example.com/style.css` instead of

`http://www.example.com/http://www.example.com/themes/in/style.css`

then remove the `$theme` from the `href` section.

hope this helps